# Parse string to DateTime, sometimes adds 1 hour (timezone)

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, timezone

I'm having a problem when I need to **parse a string to a datetime**. Sometimes it adds an hour, sometimes it doesn't. Is there any reason why it does, because I don't wan't it to add an hour.

The first example does exactly what i need.

```
string s = "2016-01-28T20:59:00.000+01:00";            
DateTime ds = DateTime.Parse(s); //gives: 28/01/2016 20:59:00
```

The second example adds an hour, I wonder why.

```
string ss = "2016-05-27T10:38:00.000+01:00";
DateTime dss = DateTime.Parse(ss); //gives: 27/05/2016 11:38:00
```

Comment: Because of DST? What timezone you use? And why don't you parse it to `DateTimeOffset` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect this happens because of daylight saving time of your current timezone.

Looks like your timezone has `UTC +01:00` in January but it has `UTC +02:00` in May. That's why your second example adds one *more* hour since it has already `01:00` hour in it's offset part.

But instead of `DateTime`-since your string has UTC offset-I would parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset).

```
DateTimeOffset ds = DateTimeOffset.Parse(s);
```

Now you have `{28.01.2016 20:59:00 +01:00}` and `{27.05.2016 10:38:00 +01:00}` as a `DateTimeOffset` values which is saved in theirs [`.DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetime) and [`.Offset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.offset) properties.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Sonor Gönül is spot on. I want to add an example, that demonstrates the influence of the time zone, by converting your example times to a timezone with same offset but with different daylight saving time setting.

```
TimeZoneInfo noDaylightSavingTz = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.SupportsDaylightSavingTime == false && x.BaseUtcOffset.Hours == 1);
string s = "2016-01-28T20:59:00.000+01:00";
DateTime ds = DateTime.Parse(s); //gives: 28/01/2016 20:59:00

string ss = "2016-05-27T10:38:00.000+01:00";
DateTime dss = DateTime.Parse(ss); //gives: 27/05/2016 11:38:00

if (noDaylightSavingTz != null)
{
    DateTime ds1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(ds, noDaylightSavingTz);
    DateTime dss1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dss, noDaylightSavingTz);
}
```

`ds1` and `dss1` will contain the time values of your input, unless you don't have any compatible timezone installed for some reason.